# Android instrumentation tests and Library projects

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I have one library project and some main projects, that depends on that library project.

I want to write tests for main projects, but the tests common functions should be placed in the library project to reduce code duplication.

I added the following lines in the library's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile Dependencies.appCompat
    compile Dependencies.recyclerView
    compile Dependencies.cardView
    compile Dependencies.playAds
    compile Dependencies.googleAnalytics

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Unit testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

in the main `build.gradle` there is:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

But in the tests for main project I get the following error:
`error: package android.support.test.espresso does not exist` for the following line

```
import android.support.test.espresso.UiController;
```

But espresso is imported in library project. This looks like, that library project is not compiled as android test.

Can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating a separate library for the common testing code.  Otherwise, you will have testing code in the app apk.

Create a new testing library (ie "test-library"), put the common code in it.  Then create the following in "build.gradle" in the app directory.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    androidTestCompile(':test-library')
}
```

Comment: You suggestion looks very good. But in my case, `test-library` also needs `library`, because common test code depends on this library. So in the main project library code includes twice, that cause problems with its res folder. Do you know possible solution for that?